# WPF - Как сделать, чтобы в UserControl контент (добавл при использовании) не заменял контрол из самого UserControl.xaml, а дополнял в заданном месте?

Tags: c#, wpf

Объясню попонятнее.

Дело в том, что в самом UserControl есть контент. Выглядит он так (упрощенно).

```
<UserControl x:Class="Goodframework.WPF.Controls.NinePatch"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*">
            </RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        ********************
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

А вот так выглядит его использование, и там **тоже** отдельно есть контент - это грид, у которого Background=White:

```
            <sh:NinePatch Height="74" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="729,6,0,0" x:Name="ninePatch1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="93">
                <Grid Background="White"  Opacity="0.5"/>
            </sh:NinePatch>
```

Так вот, этот самый Grid - должен отображаться там, где звездочки ******* в верхнем коде, ну или хотя бы просто поверх контента самого контрола, но уж точно не вместо него как это происходит сейчас.

Как так сделать?

По моей логике, нужно просто поставить <ContentPresenter/> вместо ******, но WPF тупее меня - задумки не понял, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: `WPF тупее меня` Сильное заявление. Проверять я его конечно же не буду...

Comment: @Сергей куча претензий к нему. Например зафигом столько sealed-классов. Знаете, мой проект - мое право, чего хочу, того и хочу  :-P

Answer (score 2):

Для этих целей используются шаблоны:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Goodframework.WPF.Controls.NinePatch" ...>
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <!-- ваша разметка -->
            <ContentPresenter />
            <!-- ваша разметка -->
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Однако, при таком способе вы не сможете объявлять именованные контролы в контенте вашего. Поэтому может быть смысл перейти от UserControl к обычным контролам; наследовать их проще всего от ContentControl. Шаблон в этом случае переедет в словарь ресурсов:

```
public class NinePatch : ContentControl { }

<ResourceDictionary xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Goodframework.WPF.Controls">
    <Style TargetType="c:NinePatch">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="c:NinePatch">
                    <!-- ваша разметка -->
                    <ContentPresenter />
                    <!-- ваша разметка -->
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: "Однако, при таком способе вы не сможете объявлять именованные контролы в контенте вашего." а x:Name? А обработчики событий добавлять?

Comment: @koshkashoshka попробуйте - и узнаете

Comment: И непонятно, что все-таки поменялось при переходе на ContentControl, ведь если там не мог, то в словаре ресурсов тем более.

Comment: @koshkashoshka поменялась специальная обработка свойства Content у UserControl